# How to set the position of an Excel chart with cell value from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-charts

I'm using following method to create and position the excel chart beside table data. below code is working fine, but chart position(height) is creating problem when number of charts increase.

There is any solution for draw chart with cell value? or other thing that may be used by me to keep chart beside table data.

I want to print result of following method page by page and therefore want to place it correctly.

below is my code:

```
Excel.Application xla = new Excel.Application();
int height=75;
string uppercell = "B12";
int cell = 12;

    if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        string table_name, chart_name;
        table_name = "Ration Table";
        chart_name = "Ratio";
        string st = "";
        con.Open();
        trying(ws, st, height, uppercell, cell, table_name, chart_name);
        con.Close();

        cell = cell + 33;
        uppercell = "B" + cell;
        height = 496 + 75;//height + 300;
    }


    public void trying(Excel.Worksheet ws,string st,double height,string uppercell,int cell,string table_name,string chart_name)
    {

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(st, con);
        System.Data.DataTable dtMainSQLData = new System.Data.DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtMainSQLData);
        DataColumnCollection dcCollection = dtMainSQLData.Columns;


        //int cell = System.Int32.Parse(uppercell.Substring(1));

        //********************** Now create the chart. *****************************
        Excel.ChartObjects chartObjs = (Excel.ChartObjects)ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        //Excel.ChartObject chartObj = chartObjs.Add(left, top, width, height);

        Excel.ChartObject chartObj = chartObjs.Add(260, height, 350, 210);
        Excel.Chart xlChart = chartObj.Chart;

        //ws.Shapes.Item("xlChart").Top = (float)(double)ws.get_Range("E6").Top;//this.Controls.AddChart(this.Range["D2", "H12"]"chart1");

        int nRows = dtMainSQLData.Rows.Count;
        int nColumns = dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count;
        string upperLeftCell = uppercell;// "B10";
        int endRowNumber = System.Int32.Parse(upperLeftCell.Substring(1)) + nRows - 1;

        char endColumnLetter = System.Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(upperLeftCell[0]) + nColumns - 1);

        string upperRightCell = System.String.Format("{0}{1}", endColumnLetter, System.Int32.Parse(upperLeftCell.Substring(1)));

        string lowerRightCell = System.String.Format("{0}{1}", endColumnLetter, endRowNumber);

        Excel.Range rg = ws.get_Range(upperLeftCell, lowerRightCell);

        for (int i = cell - 1; i < dtMainSQLData.Rows.Count + cell; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j < dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count + 2; j++)
            {
                if (i == cell - 1)
                {
                    xla.Cells[i, j] = dcCollection[j - 2].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    xla.Cells[i, j] = dtMainSQLData.Rows[i - cell][j - 2].ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        //ws.Columns.AutoFit();

        //for (int i = 1; i <= dtMainSQLData.Rows.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    rg[1, i] = dtMainSQLData.Rows[i - 1][0].ToString();          //For Adding Header Text
        //    rg[2, i] = int.Parse(dtMainSQLData.Rows[i - 1][1].ToString());  //For Adding Datarow Value
        //}

            int lcellh = cell - 10;
            int rcellh = cell - 10;
            string lcellh1 = "B" + lcellh;
            string rcellh1 = "L" + rcellh;
            //-----------------------for company name and address-------------------------//
            Excel.Range chartRange3;
            ws.get_Range(lcellh1, rcellh1).Merge(false);//----------------------------------upperleft_cell, lowerright_cell

            chartRange3 = ws.get_Range(lcellh1, rcellh1);
            chartRange3.FormulaR1C1 = "BLUE BIRD FOODS (I) PVT.LTD.";//----------------------------------company name
            chartRange3.HorizontalAlignment = 3;
            chartRange3.VerticalAlignment = 3;
            chartRange3.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
            chartRange3.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.PaleVioletRed);
            chartRange3.Font.Size = 20;

            Excel.Range formatRange3;
            formatRange3 = ws.get_Range(lcellh1, rcellh1);//----------------------------------hrow_border1, hrow_border2
            formatRange3.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic);

        //------for making header font bold
        int hcell = cell - 1;
        string hleftrange = "B" + hcell;
        string hrightrange = "D" + hcell;
        Excel.Range formatRange1;
        formatRange1 = ws.get_Range(hleftrange);//----------------------------------hrow_bold
        formatRange1.EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
        formatRange1.HorizontalAlignment = 3;
        formatRange1.VerticalAlignment = 3;
        //ws.Cells[1, 3] = "Bold";

        //-------for giving broder to header
        Excel.Range formatRange2;
        formatRange2 = ws.get_Range(hleftrange, hrightrange);//----------------------------------hrow_border1, hrow_border2
        formatRange2.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic);

        //-------for giving broder to table data
        Excel.Range formatRange;
        formatRange = ws.get_Range(upperLeftCell, lowerRightCell);//----------------------------------upperLeftCell, lowerRightCell
        formatRange.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous,
        Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic,
        Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic);
        formatRange.HorizontalAlignment = 3;
        formatRange.VerticalAlignment = 3;

        //--------for giving name to the table
        int lcell = cell - 3;
        int rcell = cell - 2;
        string tleftrange = "B" + lcell;
        string trightrange = "D" + rcell;
        Excel.Range chartRange1;
        ws.get_Range(tleftrange, trightrange).Merge(false);//----------------------------------upperleft_cell, lowerright_cell

        formatRange2 = ws.get_Range(tleftrange, trightrange);
        formatRange2.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic);

        chartRange1 = ws.get_Range(tleftrange, trightrange);
        chartRange1.FormulaR1C1 = table_name;//"Ratio table";//----------------------------------table_name
        chartRange1.HorizontalAlignment = 3;
        chartRange1.VerticalAlignment = 3;
        chartRange1.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
        chartRange1.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.PaleVioletRed);
        chartRange1.Font.Size = 20;

        //--------drawing chart with range
        Excel.Range chartRange = ws.get_Range(upperLeftCell, lowerRightCell);
        xlChart.SetSourceData(chartRange, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        xlChart.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xl3DPie;

        // *******************Customize axes: ***********************
        Excel.Axis xAxis = (Excel.Axis)xlChart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory,
             Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        //xAxis.HasTitle = true;
        // xAxis.AxisTitle.Text = "X Axis";

        Excel.Axis yAxis = (Excel.Axis)xlChart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlSeriesAxis,
             Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        //yAxis.HasTitle = true;
        //yAxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Y Axis";

        Excel.Axis zAxis = (Excel.Axis)xlChart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue,
             Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        //zAxis.HasTitle = true;
        //zAxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Z Axis";
        // *********************Add title: *******************************
        xlChart.HasTitle = true;
        xlChart.ChartTitle.Text = chart_name;// "Ratio";

        // *****************Set legend:***************************
        xlChart.HasLegend = true;

    }
```